# Using OpenLayers with WPS.client

Tags: openlayers-2, wps

I am trying to make an application which will test if any of the segments (multi line layer acquired from GeoServer) intersects with polygon acquired using OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer, and if it does add it to the map. After the polygon has been selected it's added to an empty vector layer which is then used as an input in WPS.Client.

The code looks like this:

```
int = client.getProcess('server', 'JTS:intersection');                          
   for (var i=0; i<v_layer.features.length+1; i++){
   int.execute({
       inputs: {
           a: selected.features[0].geometry,
           b: segment_layer.features[i].geometry
       },
       success: function(outputs) {
           map.layers[3].addFeatures(outputs.result);
       }
   });
}
```

This works, when I tested it on just a few segments, but since this layer contains about 200 of them it crashes the browser. I couldn't find any other WPS process that I could use other than JTS:intersection.

Any suggestions?